# Using Apparat dump with FDT and ant

Tags: code-analysis, active-script

I am totally new to flash development, don't even know ActiveScript yet.
I have to improve some existing flash application, so at first I need to understand the code.
I want to use some tool for code analysis, something to visualize class dependencies and code structure. I googled and found out about Apparat tool. Now I'm struggling with it because I can not find documentation that describes how to use Apparat. I'm frustrated, but it seems to be the only such tool.

So I started with example.

I've set up apparat running on FDT following this guide:
http://www.webdevotion.be/blog/2010/06/02/how-to-get-up-and-running-with-apparat/
The example (http://blog.joa-ebert.com/2010/05/26/new-apparat-example/) builds well and creates two SWF files. (I'm using ANT builder)

Now I want to analyze existing swf and see a PNG with class dependencies. 
How should I do that?
What do I have to add and where?

Or maybe someone can explain how to use dump from windows command line? Something like

```
dump example.swf exampleAnalysis.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After resolving all dependencies (which was tricky), I managed to get dump running

```
dump -i example.swf -uml
```

But it saves the UML diagram in .DOT format which is really hard to read as Graphviz GVedit cannot zoom and exports to PNG only what you see (messy impossible to read zoomed out graph), smyrna doesn't work and zgrviewer fails to load some files.